# Angular 7: Observable failed to emit an event

Tags: angular7

I am implementing component communication using Observable but somehow i am unable to subscribe the emmited event by observable find my code below

**Service Code:**

```
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
export class MessageService {
    private subject = new Subject<any>();

    sendMessage(message: string) { 
        console.log('sendMesg',message)
        this.subject.next({ text: message });
    }
    clearMessage() {
        this.subject.next();
    }

    getMessage(): Observable<any> {
        console.log("in Message");
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

**Component 1 Code**

```
  this.http.postMethod("report/PrintReport", data).subscribe((res: any) => {
          if (res.Message == 'Print Successfull') {
            this.messageService.sendMessage('Print Successfull');
            swal("Print Successfull..!", "", "success");

          } else {
            this.messageService.sendMessage('Print Failed');
            swal("Print Failed", "", "error");
          }
        }, err => {
          this.errorHandling.checkError(err.status);
        });
```

**Component 2 Code:**

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.messageService.getMessage().subscribe(res =>{ 
    console.log('res', res); 
    }, err => {
    console.log('errrorr', err) })
    }
```

i am able to log `sendMessage` function from the service but i am unable to log result given by `getMessage` function which was subscribe on `component 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the provider of the both components is not different. Your Service should get registered in the root module of the both the components where they can share the same instance of service

Make sure that Your have registered the service in app.module to share the common instance between the components.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this,

```
getMessage(): Observable<any> {
        console.log("in Message");
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
```

can you make it as simple prop?

```
message$ = this.subject.asObservable();
```

and refer it in other component as,

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.messageService.message$.subscribe(res =>{ 
    console.log('res', res); 
    }, err => {
    console.log('errrorr', err) })
    }
```

You might be losing the observable reference somewhere.

Comment: I am facing same problem and i am new to the observables so can you please elaborate the answer ? Thanks in Advance

Comment: I tried what you suggest but still same issue, as you said i might be loosing reference but console needs to printed right? that is not printing

Comment: @pradipshinde can you check what message$ is? If it is observable, you should be able to trace subject from it.